# Can an observer visible distinguish between Rayleigh and Mie scattering of monochromatic light by a medium?

Tags: optics, condensed-matter, experimental-physics, scattering

Is there a way to visually determine that monochromatic scattered light by a medium is Rayleigh or Mie scattered by this medium?

And if there is no way to tell the difference by just looking at it, what are the methods and experiments used to determine if the monochromatic light was Rayleigh or Mie scattered by a specific medium?

Answer (score 3):

Rayleigh scattering is a special case of Mie scattering: when size of the spherical scattering center is much smaller than wavelength of light. This gives a particular pattern of directionality of the scattered light, known as *scattering phase function*. In particular, in the Rayleigh regime, scattering forward and backward has the same intensity, while in the case of larger scatterers scattering forward is much more intense.

Once you measure the phase function, you can then find whether you have Rayleigh scattering or something else (which might be neither Rayleigh nor Mie, when the scatterers are not spherical, like ice crystals leading to effects like e.g. [sun dogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_dog)).

Comment: So, a Rayleigh scattering medium in a control experiment would spread out more a laser beam than in the Mie case?

Comment: @Markoul11 depends on what you mean by spread out more. The magnitude will depend on concentration of scatterers. Scattering cross section of a molecule is **much** smaller than of e.g. a dust particle. But if we measure relative intensity in different directions of scattering, then yes, Rayleigh will be more evenly spread around.